# Pivot Sql Query Returns unwanted row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand the behavior of pivot table. Here is the query that I am executing

```
Declare @Students table (id int, name varchar(20))
insert into @Students VALUES(1, 'First Student')
insert into @Students VALUES(2, 'Second Student')
insert into @Students VALUES(3, 'Third Student')

Declare @Subjects table (id int, subject varchar(30))
insert into @Subjects VALUES (1, 'c#')
insert into @Subjects VALUES (2, 'Sql Server')
insert into @Subjects VALUES (3, 'Asp.net')
insert into @Subjects VALUES (4, 'Winforms')

Declare @StudentSubjects table (studentid int, subjectid int)
insert into @StudentSubjects VALUES(1,2)
insert into @StudentSubjects VALUES(1,3)
insert into @StudentSubjects VALUES(2,1)
insert into @StudentSubjects VALUES(2,2)

select name, [Sql Server], [Asp.net], [c#], [Winforms] from
(
    select st.name, su.[subject],
    Case When su.[subject] IS NULL OR st.name IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END as VALUE 

    FROM @Students st  FULL outer join @StudentSubjects ss on st.id = ss.studentid
    FULL Outer join @Subjects su on su.id = ss.subjectid
) as x
pivot
(
    MIN(value)
    for [subject] in ([Sql Server], [Asp.net], [c#], [Winforms])
)pv
```

the result set it returns is

[image]

I don't want the first row. How can I prevent this row to be returned. Also what is the best way to convert the Null values into false. On way that I tried is to use ISNULL() in select statement like

```
select name, ISNULL([Sql Server],'false') as [Sql Server] ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I have just added a where  condition in you select statement.Hope it helps you!

```
select name, [Sql Server], [Asp.net], [c#], [Winforms] from
(
    select st.name, su.[subject],
    Case When su.[subject] IS NULL OR st.name IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END as VALUE 
    FROM @Students st  FULL outer join @StudentSubjects ss on st.id = ss.studentid
    FULL Outer join @Subjects su on su.id = ss.subjectid
    where st.name is not null
) as x

pivot
(
    MIN(value)
    for [subject] in ([Sql Server], [Asp.net], [c#], [Winforms])
)pv
```

Comment: Tnx.. for the quick response.. :)

Comment: Can you please tell me if there is any other way to handle the null as I asked in the original post.

Comment: @ZedBee, also I am not able to find another way for setting False for NULL values. If you are happy with my ans, pls mark it as useful.

Comment: will try to get other option for Isnull(), but I 4 right now think Isnull()  is the only option 4 this.

Comment: You can use COALESCE() instead of ISNULL(). Read more abour coalesce in BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx
Some additional information: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

You can add a`where` condition in your subquery or outer query where ever you feel its comfortable.

```
select name, [Sql Server], [Asp.net], [c#], [Winforms] from
(
    select st.name, su.[subject],
    Case When su.[subject] IS NULL OR st.name IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END as VALUE 

    FROM @Students st  FULL outer join @StudentSubjects ss on st.id = ss.studentid
    FULL Outer join @Subjects su on su.id = ss.subjectid
) as x
pivot
(
    MIN(value)
    for [subject] in ([Sql Server], [Asp.net], [c#], [Winforms])
)pv
where name is not NULL
```

Or like how AK47 has mentioned